# Parsing Input File in Python

Tags: python, file-io

I have a plain text file with some data in it, that I'm trying to open and read using a Python (ver 3.2) program, and trying to load that data into a data structure within the program.

Here's what my text file looks like (file is called "data.txt")

```
NAME: Joe Smith
CLASS: Fighter
STR: 14
DEX: 7
```

Here's what my program looks like:

```
player_name = None
player_class = None
player_STR = None
player_DEX = None
f = open("data.txt")
data = f.readlines()
for d in data:
    # parse input, assign values to variables
    print(d)
f.close()
```

**My question is, how do I assign the values to the variables (something like setting player_STR = 14 within the program)?**

Answer (score 2):

```
player = {}
f = open("data.txt")
data = f.readlines()
for line in data:
    # parse input, assign values to variables
    key, value = line.split(":")
    player[key.strip()] = value.strip()
f.close()
```

now the name of your player will be `player['name']`, and the same goes for all other properties in your file.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'([\w]+): ([\w\s]+)')

f = open("data.txt")
v = dict(pattern.findall(f.read()))
player_name = v.get("name")
plater_class = v.get('class')
# ...


f.close()
```

Comment: Why go through the hussle of searching the entire file with a regex, if you know the format of the file will be a key:value pair on every line?

Comment: Did you run this code? It founds nothing. Because `"NAME: Joe Smith" != "name: Joe Smith"`

Answer (score 0):

The most direct way to do it is to assign the variables one at a time:

```
f = open("data.txt")              
for line in f:                       # loop over the file directly
    line = line.rstrip()             # remove the trailing newline
    if line.startswith('NAME: '):
        player_name = line[6:]
    elif line.startswith('CLASS: '):
        player_class = line[7:]
    elif line.startswith('STR: '):
        player_strength = int(line[5:])
    elif line.startswith('DEX: '):
        player_dexterity = int(line[5:])
    else:
        raise ValueError('Unknown attribute: %r' % line)
f.close()
```

That said, most Python programmers would stored the values in a dictionary rather than in variables.  The fields can be stripped (removing the line endings) and split with: `characteristic, value = data.rstrip().split(':')`.  If the value should be a number instead of a string, convert it with *float()* or *int()*.

Comment: how about for the sake of performance, assign the fields to the variables already? Something like strip the name, and assign the number/string to the field in object named same as the stripped string. Would that work?

Comment: Performance is a red-herring here.  The OP's task is IO bound, so the time to read the file dominates the processsing.  Also, direct variable assignment uses a dictionary (globals) behind the scences, so there isn't any essential difference between the two approaches.

Comment: What if `DEX:14` or `dex: 14`? It would be unknow attr, but is it really unknown?